# Hilbert polynomial of algebraic variety with 4 generators

Tags: algebraic-geometry, hilbert-polynomial

I wanted to compute the Hilbert polynomial of the algebraic variety $Z(f,f_1, f_2, f_3) \subset \mathbb{P}^5$. Here $f = a_0^3 + 4a_0^2a_5 + 2a_0a_3a_2 + 4a_0a_1a_2 + 4a_3a_5a_2 + a_1a_2^2 \in K[a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5]$ and 
\begin{align*}
    f_1 = a_0a_1 - a_3^2 \\ 
    f_2 = a_0a_2 - a_4^2 \\ 
    f_3 = a_1a_2 - a_5^2 
\end{align*}
I know how to compute the Hilbert polynomial when the algebraic variety would just be $Z(f)$, but for a variety generated by more then one polynomial I have no idea. Can someone help me?

Comment: When you say you "know how to compute the Hilbert polynomial" for a variety given as a zero section of just one polynomial, what method are you referring to? There's a good chance it generalizes to multiple polynomials, but without knowing the method it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: The method I follow is the one explained here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3494291/calculate-hilbert-polynomials-in-mathbbp2?fbclid=IwAR2KvgqT9VLs0sPBodq1Z-12IOOqfOfcIg2h61IyX_ZxFdiuzqf6G-FH0Eo since this is the same as in Hartshorne.

Comment: Good news: that generalizes! Your graded free resolution of the coordinate algebra will be more complicated, but that method will work just fine for you and this problem.